# Momentjs : How to prevent "Invalid date"?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, invalidation

I have the following code :

```
var fomattedDate = moment(myDate).format("L");
```

Sometimes `moment(myDate).format("L")` returns "Invalid date", I want to know if there is a way to prevent that and return an empty string instead.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### TL;DR

If your goal is to find out whether you have a valid date, use Moment's `isValid`:

```
var end_date_moment, end_date;
jsonNC.end_date = jsonNC.end_date.replace(" ", "T");
end_date_moment = moment(jsonNC.end_date);
end_date = end_date_moment.isValid() ? end_date_moment.format("L") : "";
```

...which will use `""` for the `end_date` string if the date is invalid.

#### Details

There are two very different things going on here.

First:

`0000-00-00T00:00:00` **is** an invalid date. There's no month prior to January (which is month #1 in that format), nor a day of a month prior to day #1. So `0000-00-00` makes no sense.

`0000-01-01T00:00:00` would be valid — and `moment("0000-01-01T00:00:00").format("L")` happily returns `"01/01/0000"` for it.

If you use a valid date (such as your `2015-01-01T00:00:00` example), the code is fine.

Second:

> ```
> console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(end_date));
> ```
>
> It returns [object String] even with a valid date, so the if condition doesn't working in my case.

Of course it does: `format` returns a string, and you're using `format` to get `end_date`.

If you want to know if a MomentJS object has an invalid date, you can check like this:

```
if (theMomentObject.isValid()) {
    // It has as valid date
} else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

If you want to know if a `Date` object has an invalid date:

```
if (!isNaN(theDateObject)) {
    // It has as valid date
} else {
    // It doesn't
}
```

...because `isNaN` will coerce the date to its primitive form, which is the underlying number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT, and when a date has an "invalid" date, the number it contains is `NaN`. So `isNaN(theDateObject)` is true when the date is invalid.

Comment: Returning `""` throws errors, safe to return `null`.

Comment: @Vaishak: The use case here is string formatting, `""` isn't going to magically throw errors.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you explain me what is `jsonNC` that you have used here?

Comment: @John: See the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28993107/1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, actually I am facing same issue and doing like this `if(moment(value_).isValid()){
                       return moment(value_).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

                       }
                       else {
                        return moment("");`, and getting `NaN` when it hits `else` statement. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Another alternative:** Custom message

```
moment.updateLocale("language_code", {
    invalidDate: "Custom Message"
});
```

Example for english with empty message:

```
moment.updateLocale("en", {
    invalidDate: ""
});
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moment-js-customize-invalid-date/