# Preventing invalid date in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this code :

```
var dt = moment(cdt).format("L");
```

At some dates `moment(cdt).format("L")` returns `Invalid date`, So how can I return an empty string instead `invalid date`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Momentjs : How to prevent "Invalid date"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993107/momentjs-how-to-prevent-invalid-date)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override the moment js default invalid date text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953566/override-the-moment-js-default-invalid-date-text)

Answer (score 2):

With moment.js you can check if a date is valid with the method `.isValid()`, for instance:

`moment(cdt, 'L', true).isValid()`

`moment("12/13/2020", "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid()` should return `False`.

Comment: Note that the isValid has to be used directly on the moment-object, not on the string returned from `.format("L")`.